# Faces dataset with/without mustaches

Tags: data-request, faces

I'm looking for a dataset with faces with a label that indicates if the face contains a mustache. I already discovered that CelebA has those kinds of labels but haven't found another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Face and Gesture Recognition Research Network (FG-NET) aging database should, among others, contain this kind of labels.
I found a download-link in a comment on researchgate (www.researchgate.net/post/Does_anyone_have_a_working_link_to_the_FG-NET_ageing_database_or_any_other_ageing_database/amp)

Comment: http://yanweifu.github.io/FG_NET_data/index.html